# calling a function from class vs object in python

Tags: python, function, class, object

I was actually going through [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) python docs and came across this example

```
>>> class D(object):
     def f(self, x):
          return x

>>> d = D()
>>> D.__dict__['f'] # Stored internally as a function
<function f at 0x00C45070>
>>> id(D.__dict__['f']) # Memory location
49294384
>>> D.f             # Get from a class becomes an unbound method
<unbound method D.f>
>>> id(D.f )
48549440
>>> d.f             # Get from an instance becomes a bound method
<bound method D.f of <__main__.D object at 0x00B18C90>>
>>> id(d.f)
48549440
```

So from the above code, I understood that python stores the `function definition/declaration` of a class as a separate object internally inside class `__dict__` variable, when we access directly using `__dict__` variable it has memory location as `49294384`

But why does it is showing as different function/method object with different `memory location 48549440` when accessed through `Class or Object?` like `D.f and d.f`

was it not supposed to refer to the same object when we access using the `__dict__` variable?. If so why?

Comment: Your code is from Python 2, but the docs you link to are Python 3. "Unbound methods" no longer exist in Python 3.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Why do different methods have the same id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173479/why-do-different-methods-of-same-object-have-the-same-id)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yeah sorry for that, I was using Python 2.7, but even the code in documentation  is same

Answer (score 2):

`D.f` is a function taking one argument (`self`)

```
x = D.f
x(d)
```

`d.f` is a "bound method", i.e. a function where the `self` argument has already been filled in.  You can say

```
x = d.f
x()
```

Therefor it cannot be the same thing as `D.f`, and has to be on a different location.

Comment: If you look at my example when I access the function as an attribute the memory location of both ways `D.f and d.f` was same which I was confused about and what was that behaviour was all about?

Comment: Is the `id` the same thing as 'the memory location'?

Comment: Yes exactly, when I refer to memory location it is id

Comment: The expression `d.f` results in a temporary object.  Calling it multiple times may result in different results (but memory may be reused).  Try `[id(x) for x in (d.f, d.f, D.f, D.f)]` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

xtofi explained the difference between descriptor objects (unbound) and bound methods.

I think the missing part is that *bound methods are not kept in memory*, and they are actually created every time you access them. (You may get the same memory location, but it's not the same object).

**Why?**
Because on every call on a descriptor may result in a different behavior. Here is an example to explain this idea.

```
class A(object):
    i = 'a'

    @property
    def name(self):
        if A.i == 'a':
            return self.fa()
        else:
            return self.fb()

    def fa(self):
        print 'one function'

    def fb(self):
        print 'another function'
```

Calling the function `name` on an instance of A results in different function calls.